How can I Insert data in PDF via python on the PDF form having input field ? I am using pypdf
I am trying to automate the PDF form input process on my PDF form having input fields. I have extracted the form fields and data structures via following method :
from pypdf import PdfWriter, PdfReader,generic

import pypdf
def extract_form_fields(pdf_path):
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as file:
        reader = PdfReader(file)
        fields = reader.get_fields()
        return fields

pdf_path = './form.pdf'
form_fields = extract_form_fields(pdf_path)

And I am getting field details :
Field Name: topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].T3[1]
Field Attributes: {'/T': 'T3[1]', '/FT': '/Tx', '/Parent': {'/Kids': [IndirectObject(103, 0, 1808139782480),
IndirectObject(432, 0, 1808139782480), IndirectObject(433, 0, 1808139782480), IndirectObject(104, 0, 1808139782480), IndirectObject(454, 0, 1808139782480),
IndirectObject(455, 0, 1808139782480), IndirectObject(456, 0, 1808139782480), IndirectObject(457, 0, 1808139782480), IndirectObject(107, 0, 1808139782480), IndirectObject(108, 0, 1808139782480),
IndirectObject(109, 0, 1808139782480), IndirectObject(113, 0, 1808139782480), IndirectObject(486, 0, 1808139782480), IndirectObject(115, 0, 1808139782480), IndirectObject(490, 0, 1808139782480),
IndirectObject(491, 0, 1808139782480), IndirectObject(492, 0, 1808139782480), IndirectObject(116, 0, 1808139782480), IndirectObject(495, 0, 1808139782480), IndirectObject(117, 0, 1808139782480),
IndirectObject(498, 0, 1808139782480), IndirectObject(499, 0, 1808139782480), IndirectObject(500, 0, 1808139782480), IndirectObject(501, 0, 1808139782480), IndirectObject(118, 0, 1808139782480),
IndirectObject(504, 0, 1808139782480), IndirectObject(505, 0, 1808139782480)], '/Parent': IndirectObject(101, 0, 1808139782480), '/T': 'Page1[0]'}, '/TU': ' E-Mail
And the updating the pdf with following method:
'''
def fill_pdf_field(pdf_path, field_name, field_value, output_path):
with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as file:
reader = PdfReader(file)
writer = PdfWriter()
    for page_num in range(len(reader.pages)):
        page = reader.pages[page_num]
        if '/Annots' in page:
            for annot in page['/Annots']:
                if '/T' in annot.get_object() and annot['/T'] == field_name:
                    annot.update({
                        generic.NameObject('/V'): generic.create_string_object(field_value)
                    })

            
        writer.add_page(page)

        with open(output_path, 'wb') as output_file:
        writer.write(output_file)

     pdf_path = './form.pdf'
     output_path = './updated_form.pdf'
    field_name = 'topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].T3[1]'
    field_value = 'filled value test for email'

 fill_pdf_field(pdf_path, field_name, field_value, output_path)

'''
With fill_pdf_field PDF is written and new file is created but, the input is not rectified. When I try to check with extract_form_fields method, the fields are not available. When I open the file on browser, form is readable. When I write the fields with any other writer again and check back the fields will be available again.
How can I resolve this issue? And save the form via pdf?

Here is the PDF:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cdfOOg9rjmCTumQpiAQKehtMqo2Py7Uj/view?usp=sharing

Yeah, it seems like changed to more server oriented

Once I write the fields same error persists. Couldn't access the fields inside:
if field_name in fields:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
while checking with following function:
def find_field_in_pdf(pdf_file_path, field_name):
with open(pdf_file_path, 'rb') as file:
reader = PdfReader(file)
fields = reader.get_fields()
if field_name in fields:
return True
else:
return False

This is the solution required for an  immigration consultation agency who works for some specific countries candidates and they are required to fill every data shared by customers on bulk. So they want to fill the form from the data shared by customers on google form/excel sheet. So possible automation is the solution for them

In summary for one application around 4/5 different froms needs to be filled for embassy. If they are required to process 100  candidates data a day only, that will be lots of tasks.  Filling data from excel is will be the good solution as per my understanding, but I am stucking at filling generic data itself.
